# wifi detected but it does not show

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

i have wifi not working i searched the web for a weak and it did not find a solution :(

the out put of    `lspci -nn | grep Network` is :

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list` I have :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

also I have installed :

```
sudo apt-get install wireless-tools wpasupplicant network-manager-gnome
```

I even install the driver manually from [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/stable/kernel/firmware-iwlwifi), all that did not work any idea what is going on.

Comment: it says  : bash: modprobe: command not found

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:192 kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x563962d11340 path=/lib/modules/4.19.0-6-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko error=No such file or directory
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.

Comment: no upgrades found

Comment: same problem dude. And same network card! Did you find any solution?